# SQL UPDATE Query is failing silently, I suspect an enemy doublequote

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I have an ASP.NET application with C# behind. The application gets data from WebServices and then it should execute the below update.

```
sqlQueryString2 = "
UPDATE CI
SET
 platform =@platform ,
 wstart = @wstart,
 wend = @wend,
 model = @model,
 productDescription = @productDescription,
 scanflag = @scanflag     
WHERE  serial = @serial ";
```

I realized that my application seems to be looping when certain values are returned from the Web service. The UPDATE is sent, doesn't commit, and then it is picked up again on the next loop as needing to be updated.

I did a trace in SQL(Server 2005) and this is what is hitting the server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
UPDATE CI 
SET 
 platform =@platform ,
 wstart = @wstart,
 wend = @wend,
 model = @model,
 productDescription = @productDescription,
 scanflag = @scanflag 
WHERE
 serial = @serial ',N'
 @serial nvarchar(11),
 @platform nvarchar(23),
 @wstart varchar(10),
 @wend nvarchar(10),
 @model nvarchar(24),
 @productDescription nvarchar(35),
 @scanflag nvarchar(1)',
 @serial=N'H01170RAHS6',
 @platform=N'Client Computer - Apple',
 @wstart=N'05/09/2011',
 @wend=N'05/09/2012',
 @model=N'iMac (20-inch, Mid 2009)',
 @productDescription=N'IMAC 20"/2.26/2X1GB/160GB/SD/MSE/KB',
 @scanflag=N'Y'
```

I suspect that the single doublequote in the productDescription might be throwing it, but I have had a bugger of a time trying to strip it out or replace it with (in.).
I think part of my issue on that front is the value stored when it is populated by the WebServices server is escaped as I can see it as "IMAC 20\"/2.26/2X1GB/160GB/SD/MSE/KB" in the watch list.
 I have tried replacing the escaped and non escaped quote with String.Replace as well as a RegEx statement. 
TBH I'm not even sure I'm on the right track with the quote. I'm only looking at it because not all returns contain one and they don't all loop.

Comment: Can you show more of the code, e.g. how does the loop get constructed? What criteria are you using to determine which @serial values to update?

Comment: How are you making this database call?  A double quote in a parameter throwing off your update statement just screams [Sql Injection Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)...

Comment: I've done updates like this in the past that have double quotes in them and not had a problem, so I'm not sure that's the problem (but I could be wrong).  Does the SQL Profiler show any writes on that statement?

Comment: @Aron Bertrand- the loop is built from a return on this query:  string countQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CI WHERE ([wend] IS NULL AND [scanflag] = 'N')";   I do a COUNT on it to determine how many entries I need to populate then I run it without the COUNT for each one in the list. Basically I have a list of serial numbers in SQL and I check for 2 conditions the wend and scanflag values. when I get a return from web services with all of the data I write it out and set the scan flag from 'N' to 'Y'

Comment: @Michael I'm not concerned about an injection. This is an internal app with no text entry. I capture serial numbers from a variety of sources:WMI, other databases, and manual imports of CSV data(only me). The double quote is part of a return from Apple's GSX Web Service.

Comment: @user1431356 OK... but if Apple names their next Macbook `'; Drop Table CI;--`, don't come crying to me...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson LOL, that is actually very possible :p

Comment: @CodingGorilla No. I am also manually running SELECT * from CI WHERE serial = 'H01170RAHS6' and I get 1 row with all fields NULL except scanFlag which is set to 'N'. I am also not getting an exception thrown by the query either.

Comment: did you try the code profiler sent in SSMS?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson LOL, still not worried, they would name it iDrop iTable anyway :P Thanks, all, found the issue noted below, turned out to be a logic issue in my handling of serials that turned out to be invalid. When WebServices threw an exception I removed the last character and re-ran. The invoices Apple sent us somehow had an extra character on some serial numbers :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes should not be a problem: inside of a string, they are just another character. (They have meaning *outside* of string constants but that is not what's going on here.)

I strongly suspect your problem is not a SQL syntax error. If it were, you'd see it show up in multiple places.

For example, you would see them in SQL Profiler (if you included Errors and Exceptions in your trace). You could also run that exact SQL query you just pasted into SSMS and see that it does/does not work. More to the point, you would be getting a SQL exception on the C# side if the query returns an error. If none of those things are happening, then your query would appear to be working.

More likely, the query is running, but *not doing anything*, so you are picking up the same records over and over as needing updating. Again, running in SSMS will give you the "1 row(s) updated" message that should help you track this problem down.

Comment: Just figured it out. After trying to add the same data manually I discovered that somehow the Serial started as 'H01170RAHS6W' then was truncated to 'H01170RAHS6' in code. So the UPDATE was trying to update a value that wasn't in the DB. The query structure was valid which it why it didn't throw an exception back to the application.